# Soft keyboard keeps popping up

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, android-softkeyboard

I've implemented an app with a NavigationDrawer and some Fragments.
But everytime I change Fragment with the NavigationDrawer, the soft keyboard keeps popping up, even if there's no EditText on the screen.

How can I solve this?

Comment: have you found any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding this to your manifest for the activity:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this line of code in your activity

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
```

And try with adding to fragment also.

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This in your BaseActivity or Main Activity

```
 View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
        if (view != null) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
View view = this.getCurrentFocus();

if (view != null) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

This helped me out. I hope it works.